# free anonym https proxy list?

Tags: proxy, https, anonymized

i found only this one:

https://proxify.com/

"POST access and interactive content are available only to paid Proxify subscribers"

does anyone has a link to a "free" anonym https proxy? are there any?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big dislike of "open proxys" as the one you're looking for due to the all the bad things you can do with them, if you want to surf the web anonymously you can always install a Tor Client, check http://www.torproject.org/ to download it.